# He works here vs He doesn't work here

Tags: grammar, verbs

There are two sentences:

```
He works here.
```

and

```
He doesn't work here.
```

Why don't we use `He doesn't works here`. What is the rule that governs when to use `s` at the end of a verb?

Comment: This is true not only of "does" but all auxiliary verbs.  Auxiliary verbs are followed by nonfinite verb forms such as infinitives (usually bare infinitives - "he must go", "she will see", "it could do", "he does know", "she doesn't drink") or participles ("he has gone", "she is walking").

Comment: I'd just like to jump in here and belabor the obvious. There's no difference here between "does," "does not," and "doesn't." So all of these constructions are correct: He does work here; He doesn't work here; He does not work here. In all of those cases, the word "does" (or "does not" or "doesn't") should be followed by "work," not by "works." They're all comparable to "He does swim," or "He does understand."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is already the auxiliary verb `does(n’t)`  which discriminates the subject.